# Only unit in condo building with water hammer

Tags: heating, boiler, water-hammer

This exchange is always helpful. I read a similar post for some ideas, but this situation is slightly different.

I have hydronic baseboard heating with a common boiler in the garage under the building. We discovered AFTER we bought the place  that there is a terrifyingly loud water hammer when the heat shuts off. It is so loud that we can’t run the heat at night because it wakes some of us up. It is in EVERY room.

I understand generally what causes these things. I had a boiler guy out (on my dime) to diagnose, and he says the 15psi coming from the boiler is too much, causing a jolt that rocks the system when the valve to my zone closes. That said, as far as I can tell, I may be the only unit with this issue, and it is consistently loud, regardless of how many other units may be calling for heat at the same time. How can that be?

It’s tricky because it’s either going to be HOA footing the bill or myself, and I have not yet come up with an idea for how to really dig deeper without tearing my floors apart. Any ideas? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you sure it's water hammer?  That's caused by a column of water suddenly being blocked and the momentum of the water slams into the blockage causing the bang.  Assuming this hydronic system has a circulating pump, another possibility is that the pump itself is not well supported and when it turns on or off it causes the pipe to bang.  Either way it should be fixed.  Over time water hammer will cause damage.

Comment: Pretty positive. I had a boiler guy out and that was his diagnosis, BUT he had no speculation as to why my unit and not others. The pump (which is shared) is located in the boiler room beneath all of the units. Turns out my next door neighbor is having the same issue.